# Finding even values in a table MySQL

Tags: mysql

In MySQL, i have a table with a column full of positive integers and i want to filter out all the odd integers. It seems like there is nothing in the MySQL documentation. I tried the following query.

```
select kapsule.owner_name, 
       kapsule.owner_domain, 
       count(xform_action) 
  from kapsule, rec_xform 
 where rec_xform.g_conf_id=kapsule.g_conf_id 
   and (count(xform_action))%2=0 
 group by kapsule.owner_name;
```

I want to keep only those values where count(xform_action) is even. The table looks like this.

Comment: Try this:- select kapsule.owner_name, kapsule.owner_domain, count(xform_action) from kapsule, rec_xform where rec_xform.g_conf_id=kapsule.g_conf_id group by kapsule.owner_name having (count(xform_action))%2=0;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To filter out resultset after `GROUP BY` you need to use `HAVING` clause.
`WHERE` clause is used to filter source rows before `GROUP BY` occurs.

Try

```
SELECT k.owner_name, 
       k.owner_domain, 
       COUNT(x.xform_action) cnt -- < you probably meant to use SUM() instead of COUNT() here
  FROM kapsule k JOIN rec_xform x -- < use JOIN notation for clarity
    ON x.g_conf_id = k.g_conf_id 
 GROUP BY k.owner_name
HAVING cnt % 2 = 0
```

*You probably meant to use [`SUM()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_sum) (sums values of a column of all rows in a group) aggregate instead of [`COUNT()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_count) (returns number of rows in a group)*

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e27f7/3)** demo *(for both `SUM()` and `COUNT()`)*

Answer (score 0):

For aggregate functions like `COUNT(*)` using `GROUP BY` you need to use `HAVING` clause

```
select kapsule.owner_name, kapsule.owner_domain, 
count(xform_action) from kapsule,   rec_xform 
where rec_xform.g_conf_id=kapsule.g_conf_id and 
group by kapsule.owner_name, kapsule.owner_domain
HAVING (count(xform_action))%2=0
```

or you could use alias (i.e. AS) like:

```
select kapsule.owner_name, kapsule.owner_domain, 
count(xform_action) count_form from kapsule,   rec_xform 
where rec_xform.g_conf_id=kapsule.g_conf_id and 
group by kapsule.owner_name, kapsule.owner_domain
HAVING count_form%2=0
```

And you could use JOIN as more efficient than the old one of joining tables. And by the way
if you have GROUP BY the fields before the aggregate function should be in GROUP BY like:

```
select kapsule.owner_name, kapsule.owner_domain, 
count(xform_action) count_form from kapsule A
INNER JOIN rec_xform B
ON A.g_conf_id=B.g_conf_id and 
GROUP BY by A.owner_name, A.owner_domain
HAVING count_form%2=0
```

See examples [here](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-having.aspx)